# Jplayer Playlist Will Not Work in Android or iOS

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jplayer, playlist

My implementation of Jplayer appears to be working everywhere but on mobile and tablet, basically Android and iOS. When opened on Android, the playlist play buttons are disabled and the song links are not clickable.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, [
        {
            title: "Commerical",
            mp3: "/content/audio/commercial.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Characters",
            mp3: "/content/audio/characters.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Attitude",
            mp3: "/content/audio/attitude.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Business",
            mp3: "/content/audio/business.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Narrator",
            mp3: "/content/audio/narrator.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Younger",
            mp3: "/content/audio/younger.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Guy Next Door",
            mp3: "/content/audio/guy-next-door.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "English/British Accent",
            mp3: "/content/audio/english-accent.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Movie Trailers",
            mp3: "/content/audio/movie-trailers.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Smooth",
            mp3: "/content/audio/smooth.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "High Energy",
            mp3: "/content/audio/stadium-announcing.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Phone System",
            mp3: "/content/audio/phone-system.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Sam Elliot",
            mp3: "/content/audio/sam-elliot.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Stadium Announcing",
            mp3: "/content/audio/stadium-announcing.mp3"
        },
        {
            title: "Cops and Detectives",
            mp3: "/content/audio/cops-and-detectives.mp3"
        }
],
    {
        swfPath: "js",
        solution: "html,flash",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
});
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind(jQuery.jPlayer.event.play, function (event) {

    var current = myPlaylist.current,
    playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;
    jQuery.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
        if (index == current) {
            $('.audio.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.audio').hide();
            var audio = $('.audio').get(current);
            $(audio).fadeIn('slow');
            return false;

        } 
    });
});
});
```

And the html:

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" style="float:left;">
        <div class="jp-type-playlist">
            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                <ul class="jp-controls">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                <ul class="jp-toggles">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle" tabindex="1" title="shuffle">shuffle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle-off" tabindex="1" title="shuffle off">shuffle off</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-playlist">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-no-solution">
                <span>Update Required</span>
                To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To make all elements of the site work, I am using jquery version 1.7.2 (even with the migrate script, the latest jquery wouldn't recognize my page anchors).

Does anyone have experience with the jplayer playlist? TIA

Comment: I mocked up your code and had no problem playing on my iPhone 5: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3X3V9/embedded/result/n Try this sample on your devices.

Comment: This is the live site: www.fryonthefly.com Using the above code, will not play on his iOs devices nor will it play on my Android.

Comment: I extracted the relevant section of that site and it works fine by itself: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3X3V9/3/embedded/result/ Something else on the page must be interfering with the jPlayer code. Can you comment it out section by section until it works? I will continue investigating.

Comment: I do have additional jquery there that didn't even mess with your fiddle. I will edit the original question now. It's just code to hide/display content based on track selected.

Comment: I need to get more familiar with JSFiddle. Is there one for other devices?

Comment: Use the JSFiddle Share menu option to get the "Share full screen result" URL. You can browse the page from your device then. That's what I have been doing.

Comment: Here is where I have got to (added all the CSS and JS files as external resources): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3X3V9/5/ But this will not scroll down to the player now.

Comment: I moved the jPlayer to the top so I could select it onscreen and it works on iPhone: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3X3V9/6/ This is getting weirder.

Comment: Are you able to play the actual player on the live site? Or just fiddle?

Comment: Only on the fiddle. The live site player is inactive.

Comment: Could it have something to do with it being a one-page site?

Comment: At this point I am clueless. Myself, I would start commenting out other components and see when it starts working. Is there any server-side code that is different for any devices as I only captured content from the "desktop" version for the fiddle?

Comment: Nothing server side. All should be related to the responsive design, but I'll have to dig deeper. Thank you for your effort and time. I will post progress if I come across anything useful.

Comment: this may be a factor: https://github.com/lukaszfiszer/selectnav.js/

Comment: I added everything to dev.fryonthefly.com and as soon as I minimize the screen size, then the player doesn't work anymore. It has something to do with the viewport size changing, but I'm having difficulty pinpointing what exactly is going on.

Comment: That helps a lot. It is simply a styling issue. The adjacent `<div class=panel-container>` is being styled over the top of the playback by the media queries. Use Chrome to view those elements as you resize the viewport and you will see it goes over the top of the jplayer.

Comment: Wow, as soon as I commented out that div everything worked! So now I just have to figure out the best way to style. Thank you so much for your help! How do I give you the bounty? Never did that before.

Comment: Okay, that div was set to float=none when the viewport changed. All I did was float=left and all good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to a media query changing the `.panel-container` to `float: none`. Change it to `clear: both;`

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px)
.panel-container {
width: 400px;
min-height: auto;
clear: both;
```

You will need to decide on the layout for that section as the jPlayer will hang to the left on the smaller resolution.

Comment: float left seemed to fix it. I have a ton more styling fixes to make, but as long as the voiceovers are working, I'm thrilled! Thank you so much!

Comment: on my anoried phone i want screen will not off when player is working any suggestion please?